# SQL - Return results of row data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have the following table (see below) and I'd like to write a query to return me all the game numbers that have the following in all three ticket columns.

E.G. give me ALL game numbers that have 1,2 and 3 in them.

The numbers don't specifically have to be in certain columns (like 1 in Ticket1 etc...). They just have to all be in the Game's row.

I'd post what I have of the query so far but it's completely useless and really need a fresh pair of eyes to see if this is possible and if so, how?

[image]

Comment: This is a bad table design in my opinion.  You're probably going to need a really ugly query to find all games having 1, 2, 3 as tickets in any position.  When you find yourself writing ugly queries, you should question the table design. Instead, store each ticket across a separate row.

Comment: I agree that the table design can be better but the OP might not have the permission or ability to make those changes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I do agree with this. Do you mind elaborating on your suggestion?

Comment: @db-rocker I posted an answer which gives you an alternative table design to avoid the need for ugly queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross apply a conditional count to the union of tickets.

```
select * 
from myTable
cross apply ( 
   select count(case when ticket in (1,2,3) then ticket end) cnt
   from (
      select Ticket1  ticket 
      union
      select Ticket2  ticket 
      union
      select Ticket3  ticket
   ) t
) t
where t.cnt = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

> E.G. give me ALL game numbers that have 1,2 **and** 3 in them.
>
> The numbers don't specifically have to be in certain columns (like 1 in Ticket1 etc...). They just have to all be in the Game's row.

```
select Game 
from [table-name] 
where 
(Ticket1 ='1' and Ticket2 ='2' and Ticket3 ='3') or 
(Ticket1 ='1' and Ticket2 ='3' and Ticket3 ='2') or 
(Ticket1 ='2' and Ticket2 ='1' and Ticket3 ='3') or 
(Ticket1 ='2' and Ticket2 ='3' and Ticket3 ='1') or 
(Ticket1 ='3' and Ticket2 ='1' and Ticket3 ='2') or 
(Ticket1 ='3' and Ticket2 ='2' and Ticket3 ='1')
```

This returns 443.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
select * from Table1
where (
cast(Ticket1 as varchar(100))
+ ',' + 
cast(Ticket2 as varchar(100))
+ ',' + 
cast(Ticket3 as varchar(100))) in 
('1,2,3','1,3,2','2,1,3','2,3,1','3,1,2','3,2,1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the exact requirement so here are 2 interpretations:

To get all Game numbers that have the exact numbers 1,2,3 in the same row:

> select Game 
>   from [table-name] 
>   where 
>   Ticket1 in (1,2,3) and Ticket2 in (1,2,3) and Ticket3 in (1,2,3)

To get all Game numbers that have values containing 1,2,3 in the same row:

> select Game 
>   from [table-name] 
>   where 
>   (Ticket1 like '%1%' or Ticket1 like '%2%' or Ticket1 like '%3%')
>   and (Ticket2 like '%1%' or Ticket2 like '%2%' or Ticket2 like '%3%')
>   and (Ticket3 like '%1%' or Ticket3 like '%2%' or Ticket3 like '%3%')

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Andy looks correct, but hopefully you can see what a hassle it will be to work with your table in its current form.  Instead, I propose that you store each game-ticket relation in a separate *row*.  Here is what the first six records would look like with your current data:

```
Game | Ticket
443  | 1
443  | 2
443  | 3
444  | 57
444  | 13
444  | 33
```

Now it is easy to identify all games having a set of three certain tickets, e.g.

```
SELECT Game
FROM yourTable
WHERE Ticket IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY Game
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Ticket) = 3
```